# Sass @extend inside a media query

Tags: sass, media, extend

Right now there's no error but Sass throw me a DEPRECATION WARNING because I use an @extend inside one of my media queries.
I have something like this:

```
.root{
    color: red;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .root{
        color: blue;
    }
    .extending{
        @extend .root;
    }
}
```

The warning is set because I have a declaration of `.root` outside the media. Outside de the @media it's for the normal layout, then inside the same selector is for changing the layout of the page.
But the goal here is to have `.extending` to have its color set to blue only if `max-width` is `900px`, otherwise I don't want anything set to it.

So the question is how to use @extend inside my media query without sass throwing me an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try a @mixin rule instead of @extend.

Do you really have an idea how the generated CSS will look like? @extend is an aggregator for selectors, this may end up in very confusing CSS code.

My suggestion with @extend rules: Avoid @extending regular rules, use %placeholder rules instead.

Comment: Thanks, the placeholder could be a good solution.
I didn't knew about it, I'm relatively new to Sass.